# Create datasource in grafana (with curl)

Tags: postgresql, curl, datasource, grafana

When using the grafana API to create a datasource of an existing plugin, in this case postgresql, I send the following body

```
curl -i -XPOST --silent -H "${HEADER_ACCEPT}" -H "${HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE}" -H "${FINAL_HEADER}" "http://localhost:${GRAFANA_PORT}/api/datasources" -d '
{
  "name": "postgresql",
  "type": "postgresql",
  "host":"pg",
  "database":"dbtests",
  "user":"postgres",
  "password":"12345",
  "sslmode":"disable",
  "access":"proxy"
}'
```

obtaining the following result:

```
{"id":4,"message":"Datasource added","name":"postgresql"}
```

When accessing the grafana dashboard the following happens: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA9lb.png)

if you add the fields through the dashboard of grafana everything works correctly. Is there a problem with the plugin? Any idea what that might be? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type you have chosen is not correct. The postgresql type is called `postgres`.

So you just need to change it in the payload of your api call.

```
"type": "postgres"
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I have not tested this option ;) Thanks for your response!